# Generating 10 000 Wordpress posts using PHP and avoiding Server Timeout error

Tags: php, posts

I hope someone would be able to help me. I'm currently trying to develop a plugin which is able to generate 10 000 WP posts, each with different number (basically, 10 000 posts which title is a different number).

I was hoping to do that with a single PHP operation like this:

```
    $numbers = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $full_number;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j <= 9; $j++) {
            for ($q = 0; $q <= 9; $q++) {
                for ($k = 0; $k <= 9; $k++) {
                    for ($t = 0; $t <= 9; $t++) {
                        $post_id_number++; 
                        $numbers[0] = $i;
                        $numbers[1] = $j;
                        $numbers[2] = $q;
                        $numbers[3] = $k;
                        $numbers[4] = $t;
                        $full_number = $numbers[0] . $numbers[1] . $numbers[2] . $numbers[3] . $numbers[4];
                        $full_number_string = strval($full_number);
                        wp_insert_post( array(
                            
                            'post_title' => $full_number_string,
                            'post_type' => 'numbers'
                        ) );
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I always run into Server Timeout error. I tried using `set_time_limit()` function but then the code just keeps working infinitely after I pressed the form button. This is the form code:

```
      <div class="wrap">
      <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
      <form action="" method="post">
      </form>
      <?php
        if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
            custom_phone_numbers_generate_numbers();
            echo "submited";
        }           
      ?>
    </div>
```

Could anyone tell me a better approach? Is it possible to use AJAX in this situation? If yes, then how?

Comment: Why are you doing this though?  Also, why did you choose 10,000 as your number of posts?  Is this for testing or a specific case use?

Comment: It is for a specific purpose. I need to have 10 000 variants of data, each with a different title (a different number. 00001, 00002, 00003 .... 05060 ... 99999). And I will have to retrieve statistical data for each one as well. That's why I'm using a custom post type as it seems like the easiest option. Also, comments are needed for each number specifically.

Comment: Have you thought of doing this dynamically via ajax using the REST API?

Comment: I haven't. Unfortunately, AJAX seems way more complicated than just using built in WP PHP functions. Do you think there's no other way? There isn't any way to bypass the server timeout error?

Comment: You'll always run into server problems with so many operations. I would split the task: Do x in a single event (ajax/REST/cron). Generating 1000, waiting maybe a minute, doing the next 1000, etc. will be much less work on the server. And in case of problem you can more easily start at the one that failed. With this approach your method needs to be dynamic, i.e. "generate the posts within range [x, y]".

Comment: doing this in a single request is not possible, you will need to create these posts in batches or use CLI PHP commands to achieve this. Even if you modified PHP to raise the execution limit you would still need many minutes of time at a minimum, and you may run into other issues such as memory exhaustion, browser timeouts, or database issues. It would be unreasonable to expect to create more than 10-50 posts at a time in a browser request, possibly less for some hosts

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I see there's no workaround. Time to start using these technologies...